# Crashed when I call objective-c method in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Here is crash info:
[image]

[image]

The `LMAlertView` is a three part use objective-c,I use it for a long time and everything goes well.But when I use it in swift,something strange occured:when I code `init`,Xcode alert for me and I just tap enter key so the whole func finished automatic.But the func the Xcode showed is not the real func in LMAlertView:

**Here is the source code in LMAlertView:**

`- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;`

As you see,argument `otherButtonTitles` is lose in my code which auto complete with Xcode.

If I add `otherButtonTitles` argument into my code,it will build failed.

How can I solve this issue?If anyone could shed some light, that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift try like

```
let alertView = LMAlertView(title: "YourTitle",message:"your Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil)
```

Comment: fix it,insert "," , and I did,then Xcode showed:"type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: please have a look at this 
https://github.com/lmcd/LMAlertView/issues/58

Comment: I dont't know why Xcode didn't give me a complete func alert info.

Comment: Have you added the LMAlertView in bridging header?

Comment: This project write with oc, and I #import "LMAlertView.h"  in PCH file, in bridging file I import PCH file.

Comment: yeah,the url you gave help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the source code of LMAlertView.

**First**, in LMAlertView.h, add a new init method with an array for other titles(don't forget to comment the old one):

```
//- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSArray *)otherButtonTitles;
```

**Second**, in LMAlertView.m, implement the new init method(don't forget to comment the old one):

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSArray *)otherButtonTitles {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _delegate = delegate;
        [self setupWithTitle:title message:message cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:otherButtonTitles];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Finally**, you are able to call it in swift like this, without crashes:

```
let alertView = LMAlertView(title: "a title", message: "a message", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "cancel", otherButtonTitles: ["other title1","other title2"])
//......
```